# HttpClient 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to get data through an api and api has token header. When I get the endpoint from postman, I return data without error. But when I try to do this in c# using HttpClient there are two cases:

1. AllowAutoRedirect = false; => **"301 Moved"** code returns and I cannot receive data.
2. AllowAutoRedirect = true; => The API works but pretends to ignore the token header and gives an authorization error.

My codes is here:

```
 public async Task<string> CallWebAPIAsync()
        {

            HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

            clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            clientHandler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", "Token 5b187bd62127baace");
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30000);

                var response = await client.GetAsync(endPoint).ConfigureAwait(false);

               return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
            }
        }
```

How can I pass the header values to the redirected page?

**EDIT:**

**As @Mekroebo said, I directly redirected to the Location value returned from the response and my problem was solved.**

Comment: If the new endpoint reject the token you'll get an authorization error. Have you tried connecting to the new endpoint directly?

Comment: Where can i get new endpoint?

Comment: When a server issues the 301 error message, it send a header containing the new url in the "location" header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301.

I'm not sure, but I thought that a 301 on the HttpClient throws an exception. If you cast that exception to a WebException, can't you extract the headers, look for the "location" header and do a new request to that URI?

Comment: @Mekroebo Now I checked the header location value and I made a request to the url there and it worked. I had looked before, but I thought it was coming from the same url. There is a "/" before the endpoint parameter. Thanks a lot :)